# How to make Flexbox act responsive?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive layout but for some reason, the flexbox is only working well on a desktop. Here's my HTML and CSS:

```css
#wrapper {
   width: 960px;
   margin: auto;
}

.products {
   width: 960px;
   margin-top: 80px;
   margin-bottom: 80px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

.product-item {
   width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section id="wrapper">
    <article class="products">
 <div class="product-item">
     <p>FLOWER arrangements</p>
 </div>
 <div class="product-item">
     <p>FLOWER bouquets</p>
 </div>
 <div class="product-item">
     <p>FLOWER baskets</p>
 </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Can anyone cast a light on how to make it responsive?

Comment: Considering that you are setting a fixed `width: 960px;` in multiple places, how exactly did you expect this to be “responsive”?

Comment: how do you need it to look like on other screen sizes? this question is too broad. be precise about exactly what you want to achieve with. BTW using media query will sort out your issue.

Comment: @misorude I'm sorry, I'm still learning this stuff.

Comment: @Sanira sorry, I should've mentioned that. I need it to be squeezed on the screen as you resize it. it was a matter of using max-width instead of only width, as the guy below pointed out. my goal was to do it without using media query, but I know I'll need it at some point. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok, now I got that. If you want it to just squeezed, then you just need to have relational sizes, other than using exact size units like `px` use `%` with width. I'll try to post an answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```css
#wrapper {
 width: 960px;  /*remove this for small screen. if you use fixed width it can not responsive in smaller screen see media query below*/
 margin: auto;
}

.products {
        /*or use max-width*/
 max-width: 960px;
 margin-top: 80px;
 margin-bottom: 80px;
 display: flex;
        /*add this*/
        flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.product-item {
 width: 300px;
}

@media(max-width: 960px) {
    #wrapper {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: the width is 960px and your remove it at 767px?

Comment: my bad, I used this because most css framework/library use this as breakdown point for small devices like bootstrap. Anyways i will update it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the hard widths you've applied to the wrapper and flex container, which makes it too wide on small screens.  Set a `max-width` instead on the wrapper so it can be flexible:

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  max-width:960px;
}

.products {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.product-item {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<section id="wrapper">
  <article class="products">
    <div class="product-item">
      <p>FLOWER arrangements</p>
    </div>

    <div class="product-item">
      <p>FLOWER bouquets</p>
    </div>

    <div class="product-item">
      <p>FLOWER baskets</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```